# How to get random coordinates inside a swift UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm creating an animation function to generate imageViews randomly inside a uiView. Yet it is always returning 0,0 Please Help!

```
private func coinAnimation(image: UIImage) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = self.view.convert(self.coinsView.frame, from: self.coinsView.superview!)
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red

    let frame = coinsView.frame

    let x = randomInRange(lo: 0, hi: Int(frame.size.width - imageView.bounds.size.width))
    let y = randomInRange(lo: 0, hi: Int(frame.size.height - imageView.bounds.size.height))

    let position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        imageView.center = position
        self.coinsView.addSubview(imageView)
    }, completion: nil)
}

private func randomInRange(lo: Int, hi : Int) -> Int {
    return lo + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hi - lo + 1)))
}
```

Comment: what is lo and hi values ?, And why not use Int.random(range) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random

Comment: lo and hi are the lowest and highest values, lo being 0 and the highest value is being calculated.

Comment: Did you verify that large bound is non zero value, and don't use arc4random_uniform now we have better apis by apple :)

Comment: I will check it out :) Thank you for your help. Will give you any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the line below

```
imageView.frame = self.view.convert(self.coinsView.frame, from: self.coinsView.superview!)
```

This line is setting the same frame of `coinsView` to `imageView`. And when you are trying to get random x and y points in the below code it will always return 0. because `frame.size.width` and `imageView.bounds.size.width` are same and same goes to height.

```
let x = randomInRange(lo: 0, hi: Int(frame.size.width - imageView.bounds.size.width))
    let y = randomInRange(lo: 0, hi: Int(frame.size.height - imageView.bounds.size.height))
```

For better understanding add below line to your code to set `imageView` Frame, you need to set static frame to your image view initially.

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
```

Make sure width and height should be smaller than the width and height of coinsView's width & height

Comment: Thank you sir for the help! Sorry for the late reply but I have been working on a different feature. Just implemented it and it work fine.